# jQuery Mobile / Photoswipe / Home Page Navigation breaking

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile, photoswipe

I'm currently working on a mobile site for a client that utilizes jQuery Mobile (http://jquerymobile.com/) along with Photoswipe (http://www.photoswipe.com/) for the photo gallery.

The current issue I'm trying to resolve as of now is this:

- Go to the Photo Gallery page
- Click the "Back" button or the Logo to return to the Home page
- Try clicking on any of the first 3 nav buttons (these link to internal 'pages' (divs) within the mobile site), and nothing happens. You can see the URL get updated in the address bar but the content does not actually change, so those nav buttons are essentially dead links.

So far I've been experiencing this issue on iPhone devices and I can replicate the issue in Safari. I've racked my brain over this for hours now and can't figure out what's causing this issue.

You can see a live URL here:
http://cms.vizergy.com/vsites/Preview.aspx?siteguid=af91c21b-1717-4e57-935c-a617fed2303b

Here's my code for attaching Photoswipe to the page:

```
    /*
 * IMPORTANT!!!
 * REMEMBER TO ADD  rel="external"  to your anchor tags. 
 * If you don't this will mess with how jQuery Mobile works
 */

(function(window, $, PhotoSwipe){

     var options = {jQueryMobile: false};
     $(document).ready(function(){

     /* var activePage = $('.ui-page-active'); */

     var activePage = $('.ui-page-active');
     if($(".ui-page-active").is(".pGalOn")) {          
          photoSwipeInstance = $("ul.pGal a", activePage).photoSwipe(options,  activePage.attr('id'));
     }

          $('div.pGalOn')
               .live('pageshow', function(e){

                    var 
                         currentPage = $(e.target),
                         photoSwipeInstance = $("ul.pGal a", e.target).photoSwipe(options,  currentPage.attr('id'));

                    return true;

               })

               .live('pagehide', function(e){

                    var 
                         currentPage = $(e.target),
                         photoSwipeInstance = PhotoSwipe.getInstance(currentPage.attr('id'));

                    if (typeof photoSwipeInstance != "undefined" && photoSwipeInstance != null) {
                         Code.PhotoSwipe.detatch(photoSwipeInstance);
                    }

                    return true;

               });

     });

}(window, window.jQuery, window.Code.PhotoSwipe));
```

Any help/insight would be appreciated!

EDIT:

Got help from my brilliant developer coworker who discovered that there is a flaw in Photoswipe's code. Looks like there's a line that says if 'windowsHashChangeHandler' is null then remove all event handlers from the 'hashChange' event, rendering the back button useless. Basically change the following in your photoswipe.js file from this:

```
if (this.isBackEventSupported && this.settings.backButtonHideEnabled){         Util.Events.remove(window, 'hashchange', this.windowHashChangeHandler);

   }
```

to this:

```
if (this.isBackEventSupported && this.settings.backButtonHideEnabled && this.windowHashChangeHandler !== null){
                    Util.Events.remove(window, 'hashchange', this.windowHashChangeHandler);
               }
```

The details can be found here:
https://github.com/codecomputerlove/PhotoSwipe/pull/351